# Не запускается PyQt6 приложение из-за инициализации Qt плагинов

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt6

`PyCharm`, `Windows 10`. Установил `PyQt6` через *File->Settings*, всё успешно установилось.

Код приложения

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

При запуске появляется это

[image: Сообщение об ошибке]

**Как я пробовал исправить**

После каждой попытки перезагружал `PyCharm` и компьютер, ничего не помогло.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368453/application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initialized

Как я понял указанные файлы надо было скопировать в папку с *python.exe* (в виртуальном окружении моего проекта в папку *Scripts*).

2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ignw0xOKlm8&ab_channel=TECHTUBE

Скопировать папку *Packages* в *pyqt5_tools/Qt/bin*, но я не нашёл у себя ни *pyqt5_tools*, ни *pyqt6_tools* или вообще какой-либо папки, в имени которой есть *_tools*.

3. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302774/error-from-create-a-reference-to-the-qgsapplication

Не нашёл у себя файл *python-qgis.bat*.

4. Пробовал установить `PyQt6` через терминал `PyCharm` и просто через консоль `Windows`.

```
pip3 install pyqt6
```

Как решить эту проблему? Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь способы?

Comment: pip install pyqt6-tools

Comment: @Александр установил pyqt6-tools через File->Settings (сначала не устанавливалось, потом поменял версию python с 3.11 на 3.9 и всё установилось). Теперь при запуске вылетает **ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: Не найдена указанная процедура**.

Comment: pip install PyQt6

Comment: pip install PyQt6-Qt6

Comment: pip install PySide6

Comment: PySide6 тоже обёртка над Qt6 только от официального разработчика Qt.

Comment: @Александр ввёл в терминал pycharm _pip install PyQt6_ и _pip install PyQt6-Qt6_, пишет _Requirement already satisfied_. pyside6 ещё до pyqt устанавливал, там та же проблема, при запуске появляется окно из картинки в моём вопросе.

Comment: pip install PyQt6-Qt6 -U

Comment: Я обычно через командную строку устанавливаю (то есть глобально) модули, а в проекте PyCharm указываю путь до нужного интерпретатора Python.

Comment: @Александр тоже так делал. Папки pyqt6 скачиваются рядом с `python.exe` в _Lib/site-packages/_. Далее при создании проекта в настройке вирт. окружения стоит путь к тому `python.exe`. А потом когда в коде пишу `import PyQt6`, PyQt6 подчеркивается красным и говорит что модуль не найден.

Comment: А вне PyCharm работает?

Comment: Если бы вы делали как я у вас бы работало).